# Excel VBA macro send a mouse selection of current workbook as attachment to an email

Tags: excel, vba, email

How I can replace "Range("A1:M35")" in below code with a range selected by the mouse?

[Excel VBA macro send a selection of current workbook as attachment to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545903/excel-vba-macro-send-a-selection-of-current-workbook-as-attachment-to-an-email?newreg=f222d68758cb449e87abc74f9b71b9ad)

```
Sub Mail_to_recipients()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim myDataRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim sMail_ids As String
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim FileExt As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileFullPath As String
Dim FileFormat As Variant
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M35").Copy Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    Wb2.Sheets(1).Name = Wb1.ActiveSheet.Name

    'Below code will get the File Extension and
    'the file format which we want to save the copy
    'of the workbook with the active sheet.

    With Wb2
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            FileExt = ".xls": FileFormat = -4143
        Else
            Select Case Wb1.FileFormat
                Case 51: FileExt = ".xlsx": FileFormat = 51
                Case 52:
                    If .HasVBProject Then
                        FileExt = ".xlsm": FileFormat = 52
                    Else
                        FileExt = ".xlsx": FileFormat = 51
                    End If
                Case 56: FileExt = ".xls": FileFormat = 56
                Case Else: FileExt = ".xlsb": FileFormat = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    'Save your workbook in your temp folder of your system
    'below code gets the full path of the temporary folder
    'in your system

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    'Now append a date and time stamp
    'in your new file

    TempFileName = Wb1.Name & "-" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    'Complete path of the file where it is saved
    FileFullPath = TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExt

    'Now save your currect workbook at the above path
    Wb2.SaveAs FileFullPath, FileFormat:=FileFormat

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    Set myDataRng = Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("AJ5:AJ10" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AJ").End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Run a loop to extract email ids from the 2nd column.
    For Each cell In myDataRng
        If Trim(sMail_ids) = "" Then
            sMail_ids = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        Else
            sMail_ids = sMail_ids & vbCrLf & ";" & cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next cell

    Set myDataRng = Nothing         ' Clear the range.

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = sMail_ids
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Weekindeling week " & Range("K1")
        .Attachments.Add FileFullPath
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Since mail has been sent with the attachment
    'Now close and delete the temp file from the
    'temp folder
    Wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Kill FileFullPath

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I have tried to replace the range with below code, but it doesn't work :(

```
Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                       RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try replacing this code part:

```
    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M35").Copy Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

with:

```
    Dim rngC as Range, arrW() As Double, i As Long
    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook: Set rngC = Selection
    'place the column width in the arrW array:
    ReDim arrW(1 To rng.Columns.Count)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrW)
        arrW(i) = rngC.Columns(i).ColumnWidth
    Next

    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    rngC.Copy Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    'adjust the column width according to arrW memorized columns width:
    For i = 1 to UBound(arrW)
         Wb2.Sheets(1).cells(1, i).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = arrW(i)
    Next i
```

The above suggestion works for a selection done **before running the code**. If you need to select a specific range during the code run, I can show you a solution, but you must state that...

Comment: +1  that works perfectly. thanks :)  And one addtional question, how pasted range can take the same format as the original? in my particular case the width of the columns

Comment: @Jivko Ralchev When copy the range in the above way, all the format is also copied, except columns `Width` and rows `Height`. In order to obtain what you need, the code should initially place the columns width in an array and then use it to adjust the columns width in the new location.

Comment: @Jivko Ralchev Please, check the updated code. It should adjust the columns width as the selection columns ones.

Comment: Thanks.  I added this array and it happened :)
With Wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
End With

Comment: @Jivko Ralchev Of course, it works, but I thought that you have the column width larger, in order to accept a maximum string length, or something to determine you saying "...take the same format as the original? in my particular case the width of the columns"...

Comment: I see, thanks :)

Comment: @Waleed78 The above link does not point to a question posted by you...

Comment: @Waleed78 I placed an answer there, but nobody looked being interested. Anyhow, the correct/simplest solution was suggested in a comment...

Comment: Many Thanks @FaneDuru for your unique & continuous help.

Comment: @Waleed78 But do you also use another user name?

Comment: @Waleed78 No any inconvenience for me. I like understanding and it only looked strange to follow a link placed by you, bringing me to somebody else question... But you must be more attentive when place a question. The last question was not possible to be answered as you formulated it... And people here, usually, do not bother about somebody else questions if you do nat try fighting for things you do not completely understand. I do not know what happened in your case, just stay away of disputes and try being polite